# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'getBoundingClientRect')

Tags: javascript, html, css

im new to coding and want to get into stream element coding. I was following a tutorial and got the error on the title when trying to emulate an event.

Im trying to get the bar to move on event, in this case when a new follower is registered. There is also 2 other files called "fields" with code for value and the other file is "data" with info what to include.

Thanks in advance!

```js
let state = {
  "goal": {
    "value": 0
  }
};

window.addEventListener('onWidgetLoad', function(obj) {
  let data = obj.detail.session.data;
  let fieldData = obj.detail.fieldData;
  state.goal.value = fieldData.goal_total;
  progress(data)
});

window.addEventListener('onSessionUpdate', function(obj) {
  let data = obj.detail.session;
  progress(data);
});

let progress = (data) => {
  const bar = document.querySelector("#bar");
  const maxWidth = bar.getBoundingClientRect().width;
  let count = data["follower-goal"]["amount"];
  let p = (count) / (state.goal.value) * maxWidth;
  if (count >= state.goal.value) {
    p = maxWidth;
  }
  fill.style.setProperty('width', p);
};
```

```css
#bar {
  transition: 3s width;
}
```

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 961.66 61.72">
  <defs>
    <style>
      .cls-1 {
        fill: url(#linear-gradient-2);
      }

      .cls-2 {
        fill: #f15a24;
      }

      .cls-3 {
        opacity: .26;
      }

      .cls-4 {
        fill: url(#linear-gradient-3);
      }

      .cls-5 {
        fill: url(#linear-gradient);
      }

      .cls-6 {
        fill: url(#linear-gradient-4);
      }
    </style>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient" x1="480.83" y1="0" x2="480.83" y2="61.72" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity=".3"/>
      <stop offset=".37" stop-color="#f7f7f7" stop-opacity=".29"/>
      <stop offset=".56" stop-color="#ddd" stop-opacity=".26"/>
      <stop offset=".71" stop-color="#b0b0b0" stop-opacity=".21"/>
      <stop offset=".85" stop-color="#707070" stop-opacity=".13"/>
      <stop offset=".96" stop-color="#1e1e1e" stop-opacity=".04"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#000" stop-opacity="0"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-2" x1="0" y1="30.86" x2="961.66" y2="30.86" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity=".4"/>
      <stop offset=".37" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity=".34"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity=".2"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-3" x1="480.83" y1="61.72" x2="480.83" y2="0" gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
      <stop offset="0" stop-color="#fff" stop-opacity="0"/>
      <stop offset="1" stop-color="#fff"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient id="linear-gradient-4" x1="480.83" y1="0" x2="480.83" y2="61.72" xlink:href="#linear-gradient"/>
  </defs>
  <g id="BG">
    <rect class="cls-5" x="0" width="961.66" height="61.72"/>
    <path class="cls-1" d="M957.83,3.84V57.89H3.84V3.84H957.83M961.66,0H0V61.72H961.66V0h0Z"/>
  </g>
  <g>
    <rect id="Bar" class="cls-2" x="0" width="961.66" height="61.72"/>
    <g class="cls-3">
      <rect class="cls-4" x="0" width="961.66" height="61.72"/>
    </g>
    <path class="cls-6" d="M957.75,3.91V57.81H3.91V3.91H957.75M961.66,0H0V61.72H961.66V0h0Z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: ids are case sensitive. You need to capitalize it in both places, or neither place. `document.querySelector("#bar");` vs `id="Bar"`

Comment: Didn't notice that thanks! It didn't work though, but i got it to move somehow can't remember what i did.